# PHP - How to save a file in Windows-1252?

Tags: php, encoding

I work on a system that automates signature generation for outlook. The part to generate the .htm files works great. But now I need to also add files in .txt format. If I use the content without any change in the encoding, all my accentuated characters are converted to a different value for example : "é" becomes "Ã©" or "ô" becomes "Ã´".

This issue clearly looked like an encoding conflict of some sort. I tried to correct it by converting the text value input to the "Windows-1252" encoding.

```
$myText = iconv( mb_detect_encoding( $myText ) , "Windows-1252//TRANSLIT", $myText);
```

But it didn't change anything. I also tried with :

```
$myText = mb_convert_encoding($myText, "Windows-1252");
```

And it didn't work either. For both of these tests, I checked the file type with Atom (my IDE) and it recognise these files as UTF-8. But when I check on terminal with `file -I signature.txt` it responds with this encoding `signature.txt: text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1`

Note that if I manually change the encoding to Windows-1252 in Atom, the characters are correct.

Has anyone met the same problem ? Is there another way in php to specify the encoding of the file ?

Comment: Not sure if this is still the case, but in the past `mb_detect_encoding` wouldn't detect text as UTF-8 unless you passed it the strict option.

Comment: @Powerlord I forgot to mention that I also tried `$myText = mb_convert_encoding($myText, "Windows-1252", "UTF-8");`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. The code to use was (as pointed out by @Powerlord):

```
$monTexteTXT = mb_convert_encoding($monTexteTXT, "Windows-1252", "UTF-8");
```

I had a false negative when I first tried this solution because when I opened the file the characters seemed broken. But once it was opened with outlook it was fine.